# Dynamically load needed images in pug + webpack

Tags: image, webpack, require, pug-loader

I have a pug mixin for review block. Adding review, I pass what image I wanna use as a profile avatar and so I need to load it on the fly. Let's simplify code to just loading an image.

```
mixin image({src=""} = {})
  .image
    - var imageSRC = "./images/" + src + ".jpg";
    img(src=require(imageSRC))
```

The problem is I must use relative path in require function, because mixin can be used not on single page.

I've read pug documentation so I understand that there's problem with wepback, because it searches in bundled `dist` folder (where all project is bundling). So I have to set something in webpack configuration. Currently I load pug simply using pug-loader.

```js
module: {
  rules: [
  ...
  {
    test: /\.pug$/,
    loader: "pug-loader"
  }
  ...
  ]
}
```

I guess there is some plugin or extra option but I haven't found one. Perfect result for me is to get an image in base64 format.